# Alternate approach to bag of words for text based classification

Tags: tensorflow, nltk, word2vec

Im trying to predict the Genre of a movie based on its subtitles.
I have created a model using keras with the accuracy of 85% for 100 epocs.
This model uses bag of words as a input to my keras layers.

The input will be array of two lists [[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,0]], the first list is the BOW of the actual dialogue and the second list is a one-hot-encoded clases (training the movie for 4 genres).

Now I want to use Word2Vec instead of BOW for the training.
is it possible and if yes, how to approach this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much data do you have?

Comment: @Aaron data is not huge, just the subtitles of 100 movies, the training data has 170000 sentences and the test data has 45000 sentences.

Comment: You are classifying each sentence independently?

Comment: Nope, but while training I'm passing each dialogue with the label.